# Independent server side processing in node

Tags: multithreading, node.js

Is it possible, or even practical to create a node program (or sub program/loop) that executes independently of the connected clients.

So in my specific use case, I would like to make a mulitplayer game, where each turn a player preforms actions. And at the end of that turn those actions are computed. Is it possible to perform those computations at a specific time regardless of the client/players connecting?

I assume this involves the use of threads somewhere.

Possibly an easier solution would be to compute the outcome when it is observed, but this could cause difficulties if it has an influence in with other entities. But this problem has been a curiosity of mine for a while.

Answer (score 0):

Well, basically, the easiest solution would probably to run the computation onto a [cluster](http://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). This is spawning a thread who's running independent task and communicating with messages with the main thread.

If you wish however to run a completely separate process (I probably wouldn't, but it is an option), this can happen too. You then just need a communication protocol between the two process. Usually this would be handled by a messaging or a task queue system. A popular queue solving this issue is [RabbitMQ](http://www.rabbitmq.com/).

Answer (score 0):

If the computations each turn is not to heavy you could solve the issue with a simple setTimeout()

```
function turnCalculations(){
    //do loads of stuff every 30 seconds
}

setTimout(turnCalculations,30000)

//normal node server stuff here
```

This would do the turn calculations every 30 seconds regardless of users connected, but if the  calculations take to long they might block your server.